# problem setting up bash_profile

Tags: command-line, prompt

I cd to my '~' directory, then I made a bash_profile with `nano ~/.bash_profile` with an alias `alias test = 'mkdir test'`
then when i type `source ~/.bash_profile` it says

```
 -bash: alias: mk: not found
 -bash: alias: =: not found
 -bash: alias: mkdir test: not found`
```

Why is that?

Comment: it's the spaces. But also, you should be putting aliases in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` (create the file and then have your `.bashrc` source it). Don't create `.bash_profile`, as it will stop `.profile` from being read.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the whitespace around the `=`.

```
alias test='mkdir test'
```

will work.